# Closing QThread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qthread

I have a Python3 app handling a serial port on win10 using a QThread. There are times when the app crashes and the thread does not release the COM port, requiring a reboot.

I would, of course, like the thread to close the port. Can the thread find if the main program has crashed and close down gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `daemon=True`, then it is automatically destroyed when the main thread terminates, note: daemonic thread can't be joined though

### EDIT

How about wrap your code in `try...finally` block?

```
def main():
    try:
        execute_script()
    finally:
        # cleanup jobs
        qthread.quit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. I have found that now on a Python thread but the code I am using is based on a QThread from PyQt5. I cannot find that on a QThread.